# How to get Transaction ID in Google Analytics Ecommerce?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm implementing Google Analytics Ecomerce tracking for my android app.

Based on GA's document(please see the code below),
i need to create a new *Transaction.Builder* with a "Transaction Id" required. I found there's no Transaction Id returned from Google but Order ID.
- The question is how to retrieve Transaction Id or can i use Order ID instead?
the sample formatting of returned Order ID is: 12999763169054705758.1356245045384470

```
/**
 * The purchase was processed. We will send the transaction and its associated line items to Google Analytics,
 * but only if the purchase has been confirmed.
 */
public void onPurchaseCompleted() {
  Transaction myTrans = new Transaction.Builder(
      "0_123456",                                           // (String) Transaction Id, should be unique.
      (long) (2.16 * 1000000))                              // (long) Order total (in micros)
      .setAffiliation("In-App Store")                       // (String) Affiliation
      .setTotalTaxInMicros((long) (0.17 * 1000000))         // (long) Total tax (in micros)
      .setShippingCostInMicros(0)                           // (long) Total shipping cost (in micros)
      .build();

  myTrans.addItem(new Item.Builder(
      "L_789",                                              // (String) Product SKU
      "Level Pack: Space",                                  // (String) Product name
      (long) (1.99 * 1000000),                              // (long) Product price (in micros)
      (long) 1)                                             // (long) Product quantity
      .setProductCategory("Game expansions")                // (String) Product category
      .build());

    Tracker myTracker = EasyTracker.getTracker(); // Get reference to tracker.
    myTracker.sendTransaction(myTrans); // Send the transaction.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google analytics sdk for android, the `transaction id` refers to a unique identifier for each customer transaction in your ecommerce application. In any ecommerce application, each customer transaction will have a unique identifier number which can be used as a primary key while storing the transaction details in your site's database. So while sending a hit of type ecommerce to analytics, you can use this same unique id, which seems to be the `order id` in your case. 
Also note that you should use the same transaction id/order id  while sending the item details correspoding to a transaction and GA will use this for linking the transaction and item details.